# How do you use chirp?

Tags: tty, ham-radio, chirp

Chirp is an amateur radio program that will help program your radio from a computer. My radio is a Wouxun and the module is a KG-UV3D.The documentation says that is will work on this module, but there is not a setting for it so I got as close as I could.  The cable looks like this:

[image: Wouxun Cable]What I am trying to do is follow the instructions but I keep getting stuck. First, you click on the Radio link. Next, I click Download from Radio. From there I get this picture.

[image: Chirp]

After clicking ok, I get this error message:

```
could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyS0'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Once again, thank you in advance for any assistance you may have to offer.

Comment: What radio device are you trying to program? How did you connect it to your computer? You're now trying to connect to the first serial port on your computer. If that's what you want as a general user, you'll need privileges for that. I could post how to do that in an answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk, Yes please tell me how do you make it accessible for the general user?

Comment: Answer I was about to give is already provided (add yourself to the `dialout` group). However, as you appear to be using a USB serial adapter, I think you mean to use `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: @gertvdijk, thank you very much for trying but that did not work. Do you or Malt Skoruppa have any other ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: "Log out and in again" <-- Did you follow that? And if it's still not working, you *should* have another error message than in your question.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've updated my Baofeng radios. I'll dig up my cable and see if I have the same problems as you. That should rule out whether or not it's your system/radio or an issue with Chirp/Ubuntu. I can probably get it done tonight if I can remember where my cable is lol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error means you are not allowed to access `/dev/ttyS0` on your computer. Only `root` and users in the `dialout` group may access that device.

If you are running chirp as a normal user (I assume you are), the problem is probably quite simply that your user does not belong to the `dialout` group. Try the following command:

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout USERNAME
```

where you replace `USERNAME` with your own username, of course. **Log out and in again**, fire up chirp, it should now work.